# JSON/RSS to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, rss, nsdictionary

I was wondering, if there is any library in Objective-C which can convert JSON result into an array of NSDictionary automatically.

In other words, some library which can parse the JSON and make and NSDictionary array for me filled with results.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! 
You can use [Json framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) (inlude JSON.h in your viewController for example ), and you obtain your Array in only one step :

```
NSArray *rawData = [YourString JSONValue];
```

Comment: This is the the sbjson framework, which has worked beautifully for me. Big piles of deeply-nested JSON become beautiful arrays of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/source/browse/trunk/Tests/Examples.m

The docs to that is here
http://json-framework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/functions.html